# Facing BaseClassLoader.Class Not found runtime error while debugging in android at Ksoap2 call

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am using eclipse Helios for my android app development.
    I made a .Net web service and then i made an android app in which i am calling web service using Ksoap2 jar file.
    I see this link help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap for help
    I download the android ksoap2.jar file with dependencies
    Then add jar file using build path
    every thing go well but whenever i run or debug app it gives me an error
    On Call-soap method
    BaseClassLoader.Class Not found error please attach a source
    In log cat its shows couldn't find class org.ksoap2.serialization. Soap object even  the class is existing in library

```
This is my soap class

package com.nrf;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;


public class CallSoap 
{
    public String SOAP_ACTION;

    public String OPERATION_NAME; 

    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "NRF_Cargo_App";

    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:5265/NRF_Cargo_Service.asmx";

    public CallSoap() 
    { 
    }

    public String Call(String a,String b)
    {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

            pi.setName("userName");
            pi.setValue(a);
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("Password");
            pi.setValue(b);
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);  

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            Object response=null;

    try
    {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = envelope.getResponse();

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
            response=exception.toString();
    }
            return response.toString();
    }
}

This is my MainActivityclass

package com.nrf;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

Button btnlogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsign);        

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                CallSoap cs = new CallSoap();
                cs.OPERATION_NAME = "UserLogin";
                cs.SOAP_ACTION ="NRF_Cargo_App/UserLogin";
                String resp=cs.Call("Numair", "1234");

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

Please help me for making this app run
or suggest me another easy way of calling .net web-service in android.Thanks
```

For Error Log Cat

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi5hN.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click on project -->Go to BuildPath --> Configure BuildPath --> Inside Order&Export tag check library that you have import --> Ok

Then clean your project.

Comment: I tried this method multiple times.Got no success.I can give you my project sample you can try it by yourself.